Unable to start docker process - but docker is installed correctly
I want to build new Spring Boot backend and run it with docker (Dockfile and docker-compose.yml) including a volume-mapping to be able to code live.
Here's my Dockerfile (in the project directory)
FROM jelastic/maven:3.9.5-openjdk-21 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./

RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

FROM openjdk:21 AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV SPRING_DEVTOOLS_OPTIONS="restart=on-failure"

COPY --from=build /app/ .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]

and my docker-compose.yml (in the same directory)
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - SPRING_DEVTOOLS_OPTIONS=restart=on-failure

I'm starting it simply via docker-compose up
I already tried to deinstall docker desktop, restart the pc and install again but that didn't work (got it from another thread).
I want to develope locally live so I don't have to rebuild the whole thing when I make changes in the code.
The container was built but just after the boot of Spring Boot it says:
Using Docker Compose file '/app/docker-compose.yml'
Application run failed
Unable to start docker process. Is docker correctly installed?

what's your docker desktop OS ? jelastic/maven:3.9.5-openjdk-21 is linux/amd64

(Generally with compiled languages like Java you do need to rebuild at least some part of the application whenever you make a code change.  Rebuilding a Docker image isn't usually that much more expensive than rebuilding a jar file.)

@madgangmixers Ah that could be a problem. I'm using Win11 - but is there a maven for openjdk 21 for win11?

there's not much windows native docker container, your best bet is to use hyper-v/virtualization : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux
